# Spark REST API, submit application NullPointerException on Windows

Tags: windows, scala, rest, apache-spark, nullpointerexception

I used my PC as the Spark Server and at the same time as the Spark Worker, using Spark 2.3.1.

At first, I used my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
Everything works fine, I tried to run the SparkPi example (using spark-submit and spark-shell)and it is able to run without problem.
I also try to run it using REST API from Spark, with this POST string:

```
curl -X POST http://192.168.1.107:6066/v1/submissions/create --header "Content-Type:application/json" --data '{
  "action": "CreateSubmissionRequest",
  "appResource": "file:/home/Workspace/Spark/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.1.jar",
  "clientSparkVersion": "2.3.1",
  "appArgs": [ "10" ],
  "environmentVariables" : {
    "SPARK_ENV_LOADED" : "1"
  },
  "mainClass": "org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi",
  "sparkProperties": {
    "spark.jars": "file:/home/Workspace/Spark/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.1.jar",
    "spark.driver.supervise":"false",
    "spark.executor.memory": "512m",
    "spark.driver.memory": "512m",
    "spark.submit.deployMode":"cluster",
    "spark.app.name": "SparkPi",
    "spark.master": "spark://192.168.1.107:7077"
  }
}'
```

After testing this and that, I have to move to Windows, since it is will be done on Windows anyway.
I able to run the server and worker (manually), add the winutils.exe, and run the SparkPi example also using spark-shell and spark-submit, everything able to run too.
The problem is when I used the REST API, using this POST string:

```
curl -X POST http://192.168.1.107:6066/v1/submissions/create --header "Content-Type:application/json" --data '{
      "action": "CreateSubmissionRequest",
      "appResource": "file:D:/Workspace/Spark/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.1.jar",
      "clientSparkVersion": "2.3.1",
      "appArgs": [ "10" ],
      "environmentVariables" : {
        "SPARK_ENV_LOADED" : "1"
      },
      "mainClass": "org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi",
      "sparkProperties": {
        "spark.jars": "file:D:/Workspace/Spark/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.1.jar",
        "spark.driver.supervise":"false",
        "spark.executor.memory": "512m",
        "spark.driver.memory": "512m",
        "spark.submit.deployMode":"cluster",
        "spark.app.name": "SparkPi",
        "spark.master": "spark://192.168.1.107:7077"
      }
    }'
```

Only the path is a little different, but my worker always failed.
The logs said:

```
"Exception from the cluster: java.lang.NullPointerException                                                
org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner.downloadUserJar(DriverRunner.scala:151)
org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner.prepareAndRunDriver(DriverRunner.scal173)
org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner$$anon$1.run(DriverRunner.scala:92)"
```

I searched but no solutions has come yet..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally I found the cause.

I read the source from:
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/worker/DriverRunner.scala

From inspecting it, I conclude that the problem is not from Spark, but the parameter is not being read correctly. Which means somehow, I put wrong parameter format.

So, after trying out several things, this one is the right one :

```
appResource": "file:D:/Workspace/Spark/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.1.jar"
```

changed to:

```
appResource": "file:///D:/Workspace/Spark/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.1.jar"
```

And I did the same with spark.jars param.

That little differences had cost me almost 24 hours work... ~~~~